# Visual Studio 2019 : Double clicking a project in Solution Explorer opens the .csproj file instead of toggling project files visibility

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Double-clicking a project used to toggle visibility of its files, but now it opens the csproj file.
This is different than the behavior we’ve had in VS for years. It’s not very often that you have to edit the csproj file. Is there any option or tweak to get the toggling behavior back like it was before ?

Comment: Does what you say it *used* to on my PC.

Comment: @AdrianMole I have VS Pro 2019 V 16.4.1, what about you ?

Comment: I'm a mere "Community" version user (16.4.2). Maybe there's a setting somewhere: I'll have a look around (the UI for settings/options is a bit of a dog's breakfast, TBO). Maybe you could too, and post a self-answer if you strike lucky?

Comment: Use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General, untick "Open SDK-style project files..." to restore the old behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to @Hans Passant answer :
« Use **Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General**, untick "**Open SDK-style project files**..." to restore the old behavior. »

Answer (score 3):

Now the option is named as:
Open project files with double click or the enter key when supported